# Download from jquerymobile.com not same as on their demo

Tags: javascript

On their website http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/transitions/ Jquery Mobile shows their transitions work.

When I download their ZIP (from http://jquerymobile.com/download/) and I open the downloaded files from my computers hard drive, the ZIP files don't work.
For example this file: demos\transitions\index.html The transitions don't work.

Does Jquery Mobile have a corrupt ZIP file on their website? Or do I have to do anything more than just downloading the ZIP file? I thought that ZIP was all-included???

Comment: What browser, OS, and editor are you using? I can see its windows X based on thw file path slashes but what about editor and browser?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I tried Chrome and Internet Explorer. And OS = Windows 10. No editor used. I only opened the HTML files in the browser, as you see them like a normal website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Zip is not corrupted...

The problem is that those files are not meant to be run directly...

You need to put them in a server...

In my Linux box I just did this command inside the extracted folder:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

That crated a tiny server on port 8000 and then I can go to:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/demos/transitions/`

and see the file....

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. I learned something new. Is there also an explanation why this works on a server and not directly from a PC?

Comment: Things like to be in a live environment. Use virtualenv, simple server like @rodrigo-graça said, or a program that will run a LAMP, MAMP, MEAN, etc. stack or whatever for you.

Comment: @Cinzel Normaly this is caused by how the external files are called (css, js, images, etc), (path issues) in this case, it's because there is an ajax call making a "Cross origin request" ....

Comment: @Cinzel you this was the correct answer please chose it as correct... Thanks!